# Trace of six gamma matrices

Tags: clifford-algebras, traces

I need to calculate this expression:
$$Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5}) $$ 
I know that I can express this as:
$$ Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5})=-4i(g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\nu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\mu\sigma}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\alpha}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma\beta}+g^{\mu\beta}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma\alpha}+g^{\nu\rho}\epsilon^{\mu\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\nu\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\alpha\beta}+g^{\nu\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\sigma\beta}-g^{\nu\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\rho\sigma\alpha}+g^{\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}-g^{\rho\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma\beta}+g^{\rho\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma\alpha}+g^{\sigma\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\beta}-g^{\sigma\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\alpha}+g^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma})  $$
So, some of this terms are the same and some vanish. My question is how to show that.
I know that:
$$Tr(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{5})=-4i(g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\nu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\rho\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\sigma\mu\nu\rho}+g^{\sigma\beta}\epsilon^{\alpha\mu\nu\rho}-g^{\sigma\alpha}\epsilon^{\beta\mu\nu\rho}) $$
So only six terms survive, but how?

**EDIT:**
The gamma matrices are defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices), the metric tensor is
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0  & 0 \\
    0 & 0  & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $\epsilon^{ijkl}$ is Levi Civita symbol in four dimensions

Comment: I think you need to include some explanation of the symbols you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get from your 15 term expression to your 6 term expression, you can use what is sometimes called the Schouten identity, $g^{\mu [ \nu} \epsilon^{\rho \sigma \alpha \beta]} = 0$.  The square brackets denote antisymmetrization, and an antisymmetrization of 5 indices in 4 dimensions must vanish.  There are 5 terms when expanded: $g^{\mu \nu} \epsilon^{\rho \sigma \alpha \beta} + g^{\mu \rho} \epsilon^{\sigma \alpha \beta \nu} + g^{\mu \sigma} \epsilon^{\alpha \beta \nu \rho} + g^{\mu \alpha} \epsilon^{\beta \nu \rho \sigma} + g^{\mu \beta} \epsilon^{\nu \rho \sigma \alpha} = 0$.  Apply the Schouten identity three times using $g^{\mu [ \nu} \epsilon^{\rho \sigma \alpha \beta]} = 0$, $g^{\nu [ \rho} \epsilon^{\mu \sigma \alpha \beta]} = 0$ and $g^{\rho [ \mu} \epsilon^{\nu \sigma \alpha \beta]} = 0$.  The 9 terms you want to cancel will turn into 6 terms, but they are opposite sign pairs of $g^{\mu \nu} \epsilon^{\rho \sigma \alpha \beta}$, $g^{\nu \rho} \epsilon^{\mu \sigma \alpha \beta}$, $g^{\rho \mu} \epsilon^{\nu \sigma \alpha \beta}$, so they cancel.

Comment: Thank you, thanks a million @DavidChow. Just one thing, I can choose different Schouten identities and get different solutions ( I mean different six terms ) that are the same?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what your conventions are for the Clifford algebra, but let's assume that $\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu = 2 g_{\mu\nu} 1$.  The basic rule for multiplying $\gamma$ matrices is
$$
\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu = \gamma_{\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\nu} 1~,
$$
where $\gamma_{\mu\nu} = \frac12 [\gamma_\mu, \gamma_\nu]$, which generalises to
$$
\gamma_\mu \gamma_{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k} = \gamma_{\mu\nu_1\cdots\nu_k} + \sum_{i=1}^k g_{\mu\nu_i} (-1)^{i+1} \gamma_{\nu_1\cdots\widehat{\nu_i}\cdots \nu_k}~,
$$
where $\gamma_{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k}$ is the antisymmetrisation (with weight one) of $\gamma_{\nu_1} \cdots \gamma_{\nu_k}$.  In other words, there should be $k!$ terms and you divide by $k!$.  In addition, you can derive some formulae like
$$
\gamma_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_4} = \epsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_4} \gamma_5
$$
and
$$
\gamma_{\mu\nu\rho} = \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \gamma^\sigma\gamma_5
$$
where I raise and lower indices with $g$.  (There maybe a sign here which I'm too lazy to track.)  Finally, you need to use that $\gamma_\mu$, $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$, $\gamma_\mu\gamma_5$ and $\gamma_5$ are traceless.

The above rules are sufficient to arrive at the formula you wrote down.

Comment: Thank you @José. Seems like Schouten identity solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I can not comment on other answers, hence the reply. I do not agree with [@Zurab Silagadze](https://mathoverflow.net/a/222665). The identity

$$\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu \gamma_\rho = g_{\mu \nu} \gamma_\rho - g_{\mu \rho} \gamma_\nu + g_{\nu \rho} \gamma_\mu - \mathrm{i} \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \tau} \gamma^\tau \gamma^5$$

from [Pal - Representation-independent manipulations with Dirac matrices and spinors](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0703214), eq. (4.15) seems correct to me. This can explicitly be checked for fixed values of the indices. It depends on the convention of the Levi-Civita Tensor, that is $\epsilon_{0123}=1$ (implying $\epsilon^{0123}=-1$) or $\epsilon^{0123}=1$ (implying $\epsilon_{0123}=-1$), which sign has to be used.
See also [Appendix C: Dirac Matrix and Gamma Matrix Traces](https://doi.org/10.1002/9783527630097.app3) of Nagashima - Elementary Particle Physics: Quantum Field Theory and Particles.

The other steps that are done then possibly obtain an additional minus sign, as also pointed out by @José Figueroa-O'Farrill in his [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/222650). The procedure stays the same.

I was having problems with this specific formula because of the exact same sign. So hopefully this turns out useful for somebody else as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the identity $$\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu\gamma_\rho=g_{\mu\nu}\gamma_\rho-g_{\mu\rho}\gamma_\nu+g_{\nu\rho}\gamma_\mu+i\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\tau}\gamma^\tau\gamma^5$$ which can be found, for example, in [Pal - Representation-independent manipulations with Dirac matrices and spinors](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0703214) (identity 4.15, sign error in the last term was corrected — see the identity C2b in the book Y. Nagashima, Elementary Particle Physics. Volume 1: Quantum Field Theory and Particles, p. 818). With the help of this identity, traces involving $\gamma_5$ can be calculated recursively. For example, in your case we will have $$\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)=g^{\mu\nu}\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)-g^{\mu\rho}\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\nu\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)+ \\
g^{\nu\rho}\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)+i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\tau}
\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma_\tau\gamma^5\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5).$$ Now we can use $$\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)=-4i\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta},$$ and (because $\gamma^5$ anticommutes with all $\gamma^\alpha$, and $\gamma^5\gamma^5=1$) $$\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma_\tau\gamma^5\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)=-\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma_\tau\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta)=-4(g_\tau^\sigma g^{\alpha\beta}-g_\tau^\alpha g^{\sigma\beta}+g_\tau^\beta g^{\sigma\alpha}),$$
to get your desired identity $$\operatorname{Tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)=-4i\left (g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\rho\sigma\alpha\beta}-g^{\mu\rho}\epsilon^{\nu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\nu\rho}\epsilon^{\mu\sigma\alpha\beta}+g^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}-g^{\sigma\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\alpha}+g^{\sigma\alpha}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\beta}\right ).$$

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting discussion, and I would like to put there my version of this problem.

First, all identities only have any sense if basic conventional points are postulated. Namely, below I will use the following definition of four-dimensional Levi-Civita symbol:
$$
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}=-\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}=
\begin{cases}
    +1,& \text{if } \alpha\beta\gamma\delta=\text{even permutation of 0123}\\
    -1,& \text{if } \alpha\beta\gamma\delta=\text{odd permutation of 0123}.
\end{cases}
$$
Next, the definition of fifth gamma-matrix is the following:
$$
\gamma^5=\gamma_5=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3=-i\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3.
$$
With such definitions
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{{\gamma^5\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}\gamma^{\delta}}\}=\mathrm{Tr}\{{\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}\gamma^{\delta}\gamma^5}\}=-4i\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta},\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
what is checked for the component $\alpha=0,\ \beta=1,\ \gamma=2,\ \delta=3$ and is carried over to the other components which are permutations of 0123.

Further, there is the identity
$$
\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}=\eta^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}-\eta^{\alpha\gamma}\gamma^{\beta}+\eta^{\beta\gamma}\gamma^{\alpha}-i\gamma^5\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\gamma_{\delta},\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric with the signature $\{+1, -1, -1, -1\}$ and, hence, $\gamma_0=\gamma^0$, while $\gamma_\mu=-\gamma^\mu$ with $\mu=\{1, 2, 3\}$. Such defined the identity is in agreement with the version of @J.G. because $\gamma^5$ anticommutes with any of $\gamma_\mu$ and $\varepsilon^{\delta\alpha\beta\gamma}=-\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$.

Finally, we are ready to calculate the trace $\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma^{\tau}\gamma^5\}$.

First, replacing $\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma^{\gamma}$ with  the use of the identity \ref{2} one obtains
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^\gamma\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}=
\eta^{\alpha\beta}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\gamma\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}-
\eta^{\alpha\gamma}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\beta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}+
\eta^{\beta\gamma}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}-
i\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^5\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}.\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
First three terms are rewritten with the use of the identity \ref{1}.
As for the last term, let's consider the multiplier $\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^5\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}$ separately:
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^5\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}=\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\}
$$
because of anticommutation of $\gamma^5$ with both $\gamma_\mu$ and $\gamma^\mu$, further use the identity \ref{2} one more time:
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\}=
\eta^{\rho\sigma}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\tau\}-
\eta^{\rho\tau}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\sigma\}+
\eta^{\sigma\tau}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\}-
i\varepsilon^{\rho\sigma\tau\eta}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^5\gamma_\eta\}.\tag{4}\label{4}
$$
The last term vanishes (trace of product of fifth gamma-matrix with only two gamma-matrices) and every of the other terms contains the multiplier of the form
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\lambda\gamma^\nu\}=\eta_{\lambda\mu}\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\}=4\eta_{\lambda\mu}\eta^{\mu\nu}.
$$
Using this one can rewrite \ref{4} in the form
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma_\delta\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\}=
4\eta^{\rho\sigma}\eta_{\delta\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\tau}-
4\eta^{\rho\tau}\eta_{\delta\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\sigma}+
4\eta^{\sigma\tau}\eta_{\delta\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\rho}
$$
and inserting it to \ref{3} one obtains
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\{\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta\gamma^\gamma\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\tau\gamma^5\}=-4i(
 \eta^{\alpha\beta}\varepsilon^{\gamma\rho\sigma\tau}
-\eta^{\alpha\gamma}\varepsilon^{\beta\rho\sigma\tau}
+\eta^{\beta\gamma}\varepsilon^{\alpha\rho\sigma\tau}
+\eta^{\rho\sigma}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\tau}
-\eta^{\rho\tau}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\sigma}
+\eta^{\sigma\tau}\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\rho}).
$$
Note, that we have used the following transformations:
$$
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\eta_{\delta\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\tau}=
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma}_{\phantom{\alpha\beta\gamma}\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\tau}\equiv
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\lambda}\delta^\tau_\lambda=
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\tau},
$$
where $\delta^\alpha_\beta=1$ if $\alpha=\beta$ and $\delta^\alpha_\beta=0$ if $\alpha\neq\beta$ and and so on.